ForegroundService not recording audio when app loses focus
I'm making an Android app for personal use that uses porcupine to detect a custom wakeword and start google assistant.
The app is fully functioning except for the ForegroundService: whenever my app loses focus the ForegroundService remains active but it stops detecting any wakeword, however when it regains focus it works fine.
This is my Service class:
class PorcupineService : Service() {
    private val accessKey = "nuh uh"

    private var porcupineManager: PorcupineManager? = null
    private val notificationId = "zingaraccia"

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        val notification = Notification.Builder(this, notificationId)
            .setContentTitle("Zingaraccia Companion")
            .setContentText("Pronta a zingarare!")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .build()

        this.startForeground(1, notification)
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        try {
            porcupineManager = PorcupineManager.Builder()
                .setAccessKey(accessKey)
                .setKeywordPath("models/zingaraccia.ppn")
                .setModelPath("models/porcupine_params_it.pv")
                .setSensitivity(0.7f)
                .build(
                    applicationContext
                ) {
                    // start google assistant
                    val inten = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND)
                    inten.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    startActivity(inten)
                }

            porcupineManager!!.start()
        } catch (e: PorcupineException) {
            Log.e("PORCUPINE_SERVICE", e.toString())
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        try {
            porcupineManager!!.stop()
            porcupineManager!!.delete()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("PORCUPINE", e.toString())
        }
        super.onDestroy()
    }

and this is my android manifest:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MICROPHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Zingaraccia"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <service
            android:name=".PorcupineService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:foregroundServiceType="microphone"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Zingaraccia">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

What should I do?
Edit: this is my build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.spartacus04.zingaraccia"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.spartacus04.zingaraccia"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("ai.picovoice:porcupine-android:3.0.1")
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)
}


Edit your post to identify what Android API version you are targeting (gradle files).

Solved by tweaking the class a bit and using an AccessibilityService instead of a normal Service.
